# Google Sheets formula explanation

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I asked a question on StackOverflow: [Google Sheets: Join two tables together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890286/google-sheets-join-two-tables-together?noredirect=1#comment109468513_61890286)

I had to figure out how to join two tables together dynamically. I got an answer from @MattKing on how to solve my problem and his solution worked on the sample data that I had created. However, his solution merges two tables together in a single `query()` and I can't understand how that works so I need help understanding that formula. I can't implement it on my actual sheet unless I understand how it works.

Sample sheet where the formula is implemented: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nKQXHwVO8KjsOy5qvjzh-s-YYRUYlAoH-3aXYbwcKsA/edit?usp=sharing

The formula that I need to understand: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A3:G;{H4:I,IFERROR(ROW(H4:H)/{0,0,0,0}),J4:J}},"select Col1,Col2,SUM(Col3),SUM(Col4),SUM(Col5),SUM(Col6),SUM(Col7) where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label SUM(Col3)'Impressions',SUM(Col4)'Clicks',SUM(Col5)'Cost',SUM(Col6)'Leads',SUM(Col7)'Offline Leads'"))`

Part of that formula that I'm confused about: `QUERY({A3:G;{H4:I,IFERROR(ROW(H4:H)/{0,0,0,0}),J4:J}}`

I'd appreciate your help in figuring out this awesome formula!

Comment: Why not ask him on the original post?

Comment: I did, he hasn't responded yet so I was hoping for some more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see what's going on if you run this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A3:G10; {H4:I10, IFERROR(ROW(H4:H10)/{0,0,0,0}), J4:J10}})
```

but basically it's a way of offsetting columns with a division of zeros which will output #DIV error because anything divided by 0 is considered as illogical in google sheets. so...

```
=ROW(H4:H)
```

will give you row numbers on each row starting from 4 eg.:

```
4
5
6
...
```

that is then divided by 4 columns / 4 zeros which results in array of:

```
#DIV | #DIV | #DIV | #DIV
#DIV | #DIV | #DIV | #DIV
#DIV | #DIV | #DIV | #DIV
...
```

that is wrapped in `IFERROR` so all `#DIV` errors are nullified which means you are left of with 4 empty columns

so we have whatever is in H4:I then we continue with 4 empty columns and then the last column is J4:J so this way you got 7 columns in total

then these 7 columns are put in array again with whatever is in A3:G columns like:

```
A:A   B:B   C:C   D:D   E:E   F:F   G:G
H:H   I:I   #DIV  #DIV  #DIV  #DIV  J:J
```

the reason why you need this to be like presented above is because `QUERY` requires aggregation of columns when you use operations like `sum`, `min`, `max`, `avg`

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation, I got the formula to work on my report :)