# "Joining" tables in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have two tables. The first one looks somewhat like this:

```
id   name
----------
0    "abc"
1    "def"
2    "ghi"
3    "jkl"
4    "mno"
5    "pqr"
```

... and the second one looks like this:

```
id1  id2  foo
-------------
3    1    "a"
1    5    "b"
5    6    "c"
5    2    "d"
4    1    "e"
2    5    "f"
```

So, now I want a third table that is equivalent to the second one, but instead of the ids (id1 and id2), I want the name corresponding to that id. So, for instance:

```
name1  name2  foo
-----------------
"jkl"  "def"  "a"
"def"  "pqr"  "b"
...    ...    ...
```

The idea behind all of this is that I want to print the third table, but I do not want to modify it directly. Instead, I just want to alter tables one and two.

Is this somehow possible in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, actually there are two common paths to do this

1. Use formulas
2. Use Google Apps Script

Using  formulas

- Use VLOOPKUP

NOTES:

- You could use ARRAYFORMULA to do this on a single formula
- Instead of VLOOKUP you could combine INDEX and MATCH  functions

Resources

- https://support.google.com/docs Search for the function list or on the Google Sheets UI click on Help > Functions

Using Google Apps Script

In order to use Google Apps Script you should know the basics of JavaScript.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

---

Related

- [Google spreadsheet "=QUERY" join() equivalent function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14796620/1595451)
- [How to join tables using Query or Vlookup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48166016/1595451)
- [Google Sheets: Join two tables together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61890286/1595451)
- [Join tables in google sheet - full join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62641416/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({IF(F1:F="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(D1:E, A1:B, 2, 0))), F1:F}
```

[image]